# Await used after promise initialized

Tags: javascript, async-await

I would like to connect mongoDb and execute code asynchronously.

```
async function test() {
    let task = asyncTask() //return a promise
    //function still running
    await task
    //code executed only if task is resolved
}
```

Using await like that is correct ?

Comment: You can find out more at [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/p/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you use await with an async function then the code will block until the promise has either resolved or failed. You should wrap your await block in a try catch to handle any errors.

```
async function test() {
    let task = asyncTask()
    //function still running
    try {
        await task
        //code executed only if task is resolved
    } catch (err){
        //Something went wrong
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Using async/await has the same functionality as a promise, but just provides a more synchronous way of writing your code.

If you wanted to rewrite the code as a promise then it would look like:

```
function test() {
    myPromise('some arguments')
    .then(result => console.log(`Task completed: ${result}`);)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: Try catch can be avoid ?
If I use in my main:
test().then(res => ).catch(err => ) ?

Comment: The try catch is optional, but considered best practice unless you can guarantee your task will never fail, which is unlikely.

Comment: There is no need for a complicated workaround for try-catch, just use it ;)

Comment: If i call test().then( res => ).catch( err => //error throwed orginally by task), this is correct ?

Comment: @Mendes you would have to return the return the result from the awaited task before you can use it a promise chain like you've specified there in the form of `test().then(res => ).catch(err => ) `. So the function should write `return await task` otherwise it would return Promise with an undefined value

Comment: Calling test() won't return anything. You are handling the promise/async action within the function. If you want behaviour like that then you need to return a promise from your test() method. Async await expects a promise, have a read of this to understand better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Answer (score 1):

> **async/await**
>
> **async**:The word **`async`** before a `function` means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise.
>
> **await**:The keyword **`await`** makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.

**Here**

```
  async function test() {
    let task = asyncTask() //return a promise
    //function still running
    await task
    //code executed only if task is resolved
}
```

The function execution “pauses” at the line (`await task`) and resumes when the promise settles, with `task` becoming its result.

Let’s emphasize: `await` literally makes JavaScript wait until the promise settles, and then go on with the result.

If a promise resolves normally, then await promise returns the `result`. But in case of a rejection it throws the `error` .

**1.** Either as already said in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335024/1081909) We should catch that error using `try..catch`

```
async function test() {
    let task = asyncTask()
    //function still running
    try {
        await task
   } catch (err){
       throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

**2.** If we don’t have `try..catch`, then the promise generated by the call of the async function `test()` becomes rejected. We can append `.catch` to handle it:

```
async function test() {
        let task = asyncTask() //return a promise
        //function still running
        await task
        //code executed only if task is resolved
    } 
 test().catch(//error);
```

More If `.catch` is not  there, then we get an unhandled promise error. We can catch such errors using a **global event handler**.